# how to manage childrecord in html table using php?

Tags: javascript, php, datatables

i have two SQL table combine record like

```
"select master.companyName AS companyName , sub.name as Name,sub.mobile As Mobile from companyMaster as master
inner join submaster as sub ON master.id =sub.mId"
```

how to  display sub table record like this using php ,javascript or jquery in datatble?
[image]

i have fetch record using php post method in datatable and how to collapse sub record?

Comment: It might be a good idea to post the javascript that you have used so far trying to solve this conundrum ;-)

Comment: i have only simple data table and display all record directly sequential ,how to i manage like image in show